# Align bit array to 64 bit boundary C#

Tags: c#, memory-management

I have the following byte array in C# and I've been told to align it to a 64 bit boundary:

```
protected byte[] bitArray;
```

In C++ I know I can do this using memory allocation but I don't have the same control over this in C#. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to pin the array. Otherwise the GC will move it to a different alignment sooner or later. You need to keep it pinned.

Then, over-allocate by 64 bits = 8 bytes. Use a subsection of the array that is aligned by simply not using a prefix of it.

Determine the first index to use by obtaining a pointer to the array.

If you don't need a managed object you can just allocate unmanaged memory directly. This can be far less convenient, though.

Comment: That's a neat solution indeed