# Create Memory Aligned Array in C#

Tags: c#

I need to create a array that is aligned to a 64 byte boundary. I need to do this as I'm calling a DLL which uses [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions), which requires the [data to be aligned](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movdqa:vmovdqa32:vmovdqa64). Essentially I need to do this in C#:

```
void* ptr = _aligned_malloc(64 * 1024, 64);
int8_t* memory_ptr = (int8_t*)ptr;
```

I'm pretty sure I can't create an array to such a boundary naturally in C#. So one option is to create an byte array that is x+64 long, and then 'create' an array that overlays it, but with an offset at the required boundary.

The problem is how do I accomplish this, and not have a memory leak? (Memory leaking is the reason I'd rather not use the DLL to create a reference to the array and pass it to C#. Unless there is a good way to do so?)

---

Using the helpful answers below, this is what I have, hopefully it helps others:

```
public class Example : IDisposable
{
    private ulong memory_ptr;

    public unsafe Example() 
    {
        memory_ptr = (ulong)NativeMemory.AlignedAlloc(0x10000, 64);
    }

    public unsafe Span<byte> Memory => new Span<byte>((void*)memory_ptr, 0x10000);

    public unsafe void Dispose()
    {
        NativeMemory.Free((void*)memory_ptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: .NET 6 has `NativeMemory.AlignedAlloc`, which gives you a block of memory you must free with `NativeMemory.AlignedFree`.

Comment: I don't know why you stress about memory leaks, though. If you're allocating a managed array, it's handled by the garbage collector. If you're allocating native memory, use stuff like `try`/`finally` statements (or wrap it in a `SafeHandle`-derived class) to ensure you don't forget to free it. When you need to pass that managed memory to native code, pin it with `fixed` to ensure it doesn't move while the native code is running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned, .NET 6 has [`NativeMemory.AlignedAlloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.nativememory.alignedalloc?view=net-6.0). You need to make sure to call `AlignedFree` otherwise you could get a leak.

```cs
void* a = default;
try
{
    a = NativeMemory.AlignedAlloc(size * sizeof(long), 64);
    var span = new Span<long>(a, size);
    // fill span
    // call DLL with span
}
finally
{
    NativeMemory.AlignedFree(a);
}
```

A pinned `GCHandle` is another option for older versions of .NET. You then need to calculate the starting aligned offset with the following code, where `alignment` would be `64` in your case.

```cs
var ptr = (long)handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
var offset = (int) ((ptr + alignment - 1) / alignment * alignment - ptr) / sizeof(long);
```

Again you need to make sure to call `handle.Free` in a `finally`.

Comment: That looks like it will do it. Now I need to figure out how to keep the reference for the lifespan of the parent object. But that is a different question!

Comment: Put it in a `IDisposable` or `SafeHandle` class and use a `using`. Although you can't then use `Span`

Comment: Yeah, its using it as an array that's the hard part!!

Comment: Easiest way to do that if you want it in a class is to have a `AsSpan` method which you can use within a single function.

Comment: Current plan is to cast what comes back from AlignedAlloc to a ulong, and add a property `public unsafe Span<byte> Memory => new Span<byte>((void)*)_memory_ptr, 0x10000);`

Comment: The only reason to use `GCHandle` is if you want an object to remain pinned for longer periods of time (actually, it's main purpose is to access a managed object from unmanaged memory, by ensuring it does not get garbage collected while native code is running). If you need the memory to be pinned for the duration of a method call, use a `fixed` statement.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the memory leak, first you need to [pin the array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/how-to-pin-pointers-and-arrays?view=msvc-170). Pinning prevents the object pointed to from moving on the garbage-collected heap.

There's an example of something similar to what you're doing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613056/align-bit-array-to-64-bit-boundary-c-sharp).

However, that example doesn't go far enough as it only pins without controlling the initial memory allocation. To also prevent the memory leak, instead use [GCHandle.Alloc with GCHandleType.Pinned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.alloc?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Runtime_InteropServices_GCHandle_Alloc_System_Object_System_Runtime_InteropServices_GCHandleType_). Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14735571/1657610).

Comment: You probably don't need a `GCHandle`, just use a `fixed` statement to pin a managed byte array.

Comment: `Alloc` is not what avoids the memory leak, it's the `Free` afterwards, which needs to be in a `finally`

Comment: NativeMemory.AlignedAlloc() " is a thin wrapper over the C aligned_alloc API". i.e not managed memory, so pinning doesn't make sense. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: @balrob as you say, it is not managed memory; it is the managed object reference to it that is pinned.