# Why is a System.Collections.List<T>.Add faster than manual memory management?

Tags: c#, performance, pointers, low-level

Hey there I am currently experimenting with very low-level C# mainly to learn and bring my skills to the next level for a performance heavy project.
I tried to create sth like a NativeList so a List without any automatic garbage collection.
I want to use structs and manual pointer allocation to create a memory and cache-line aligned List implementation. This may look familiar for the Unity people out here.

The issue I am facing right now that I get some unexpected results after benchmarking using BenchmarkDotnet.
Reads are as expected a bit faster mainly because I use pointers directly (I assume) and array access is pretty fast in C# anyway.
Writes are a lot faster ~70% actually which is confusing but may be caused by the memory alignment.
Add however is ~5% slower and I can't figure out why.

Please note that there are zero allocations involved in the benchmark because both Lists keep their internal buffer alive. The only part left are the if conditions which are very similar to what List does internally.

Do you have some suggestions to make this even faster or can tell me why my list has slower Adds?

### Benchmark results:

| Method | Size | Mean | Error | StdDev | Ratio | RatioSD | CacheMisses/Op |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Native_Add | 100 | 934.59 ns | 5.828 ns | 4.866 ns | 1.04 | 0.01 | 2 |
| List_Add | 100 | 894.44 ns | 7.063 ns | 6.607 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 | 1 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Native_Add | 1000 | 9,463.38 ns | 183.577 ns | 162.736 ns | 1.03 | 0.03 | 16 |
| List_Add | 1000 | 9,196.11 ns | 87.191 ns | 81.558 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 | 17 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Native_Add | 10000 | 93,361.52 ns | 876.444 ns | 776.945 ns | 1.05 | 0.01 | 112 |
| List_Add | 10000 | 88,501.43 ns | 362.486 ns | 302.692 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 | 53 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Native_Get | 100 | 41.38 ns | 0.371 ns | 0.347 ns | 0.94 | 0.02 | 0 |
| List_Get | 100 | 43.93 ns | 0.849 ns | 0.794 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 | 0 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Native_Get | 1000 | 366.97 ns | 4.445 ns | 3.940 ns | 0.98 | 0.02 | 0 |
| List_Get | 1000 | 374.97 ns | 3.053 ns | 2.550 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 | 0 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Native_Get | 10000 | 3,674.04 ns | 60.222 ns | 56.331 ns | 0.98 | 0.02 | 5 |
| List_Get | 10000 | 3,733.41 ns | 35.220 ns | 32.945 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 | 4 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Native_Set | 100 | 56.57 ns | 0.357 ns | 0.279 ns | 0.34 | 0.00 | 0 |
| List_Set | 100 | 164.29 ns | 0.936 ns | 0.875 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 | 0 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Native_Set | 1000 | 493.52 ns | 8.668 ns | 8.108 ns | 0.30 | 0.00 | 1 |
| List_Set | 1000 | 1,665.81 ns | 10.073 ns | 7.865 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 | 2 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Native_Set | 10000 | 4,984.44 ns | 94.866 ns | 88.737 ns | 0.30 | 0.01 | 10 |
| List_Set | 10000 | 16,699.32 ns | 59.226 ns | 49.456 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 | 18 |

### Struct:

```cs
public unsafe struct NativeList<T> : IDisposable where T : unmanaged {
    private static readonly int MinCapacity = UnsafeUtils.CacheLineSize / sizeof(T);
    private T* _buffer;
    private int _capacity;
    private int _count;

    public int Capacity => _capacity;
    public int Count => _count;
    public T this[int index] {
        get {
            if((uint)index >= (uint)_count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
            return _buffer[index];
        }
        set {
            if((uint)index >= (uint)_count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
            _buffer[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public NativeList() {
    }

    public NativeList(int capacity) {
        if(capacity != 0) Resize(capacity);
    }

    public void Add(T value) {
        EnsureCapacity(1);
        _buffer[_count] = value;
        _count++;
    }

    public void AddRange(T* values, int count) {
        if(count == 0) return;
        EnsureCapacity(count);
        UnsafeUtils.Copy<T>(values, 0, _buffer, _count, count);
        _count += count;
    }

    public bool Remove(T value) {
        var index = IndexOf(value);
        if(index < 0) return false;
        RemoveAt(index);
        return true;
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index) {
        if(index >= _count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));

        _count--;
        if(_count != index) {
            UnsafeUtils.Copy<T>(_buffer, index + 1, _buffer, index, _count - index);
        }
    }
    public void RemoveRangeAt(int index, int count) {
        if(index < 0 || index >= _count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
        if(count < 0 || index + count > _count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));
        if(count == 0) return;

        _count -= count;
        if(_count != index) {
            UnsafeUtils.Copy<T>(_buffer, index + count, _buffer, index, _count - index);
        }
        _count -= count;
    }

    public bool Contains(T value) {
        return IndexOf(value, EqualityComparer<T>.Default) >= 0;
    }
    public bool Contains(T value, IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer) {
        return IndexOf(value, equalityComparer) >= 0;
    }
    
    public int IndexOf(T value) {
        return IndexOf(value, EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
    }
    public int IndexOf(T value, IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer) {
        for(var i = 0; i < _count; i++) {
            if(equalityComparer.Equals(((T*)_buffer)[i], value)) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    
    public void Clear() {
        _count = 0;
    }
    
    public Span<T> AsSpan() {
        return UnsafeUtils.CreateSpan<T>(_buffer, _count);
    }

    public Enumerator GetEnumerator() {
        return new Enumerator(_buffer, _count);
    }

    private void EnsureCapacity(int count) {
        var minCapacity = _count + count;
        if(minCapacity > _capacity) Resize(minCapacity);
    }

    private void Resize(int capacity) {
        capacity = Math.Max(MinCapacity, (int)BitOperations.RoundUpToPowerOf2((uint)capacity));
        _buffer = (T*)UnsafeUtils.AlignedRealloc<T>(_buffer, capacity);
        _capacity = capacity;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        if(_buffer is null) return;
        UnsafeUtils.AlignedFree(_buffer);
        _capacity = 0;
        _buffer = null;
    }

    public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<T> {
        private readonly void* _buffer;
        private readonly int _count;
        private int _index;
        
        public T Current { get; private set; }
        object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

        public Enumerator(void* buffer, int count) {
            _buffer = buffer;
            _count = count;
            _index = -1;
        }

        public bool MoveNext() {
            if(++_index >= _count) return false;
            Current = ((T*)_buffer)[_index];
            return true;
        }

        public void Reset() {
            _index = -1;
        }
        public void Dispose() {}
    }
}
```

### Benchmark:

```cs
[SimpleJob]
[MemoryDiagnoser]
[HardwareCounters(HardwareCounter.CacheMisses)]
[GroupBenchmarksBy(BenchmarkLogicalGroupRule.ByCategory, BenchmarkLogicalGroupRule.ByParams)]
public class NativeListBenchmark {
    private NativeList<int> _fullNativeList = new();
    private List<int> _fullList = new();
    private Random _random;
    
    private NativeList<int> _nativeList = new();
    private List<int> _list = new();

    [Params(100, 1000, 10_000)]
    public int Size { get; set; }

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup() {
        _random = new Random(1337);
        for(var i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
            _fullNativeList.Add(i);
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
            _fullList.Add(i);
        }
    }

    [GlobalCleanup]
    public void Cleanup() {
        _nativeList.Dispose();
        _fullNativeList.Dispose();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    [BenchmarkCategory("Add")]
    public void Native_Add() {
        _nativeList.Clear();
        for(var i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
            _nativeList.Add(_random.Next());
        }
    }
    [Benchmark]
    [BenchmarkCategory("Get")]
    public void Native_Get() {
        for(var i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
            _ = _fullNativeList[i];
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    [BenchmarkCategory("Set")]
    public void Native_Set() {
        for(var i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
            _fullNativeList[i] = i;
        }
    }

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    [BenchmarkCategory("Add")]
    public void List_Add() {
        _list.Clear();
        for(var i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
            _list.Add(_random.Next());
        }
    }

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    [BenchmarkCategory("Get")]
    public void List_Get() {
        for(var i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
            _ = _fullList[i];
        }
    }

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    [BenchmarkCategory("Set")]
    public void List_Set() {
        for(var i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
            _fullList[i] = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "a List without any automatic garbage collection" -- there is no automatic garbage collection in `List<>` either as long as your type is a value type.

Comment: `List` uses strategic placement of `AggressiveInlining` and `NoInlining` to guide the Jitter how to inline its methods. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/bc70fec98fe39e63e194e7ffa30e9d1f44b4f254/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs#L195C9-L195C59

Comment: The list itself is a class and has a reference to an array. Sure as long as you keep the reference it will never be GC. But as soon as there are no references left you rely on the GC to clear the class and the arrays memory. Same goes when resizing the list. It will create a new array and the old one get's GC after some time.

Comment: Side note: unlike C++ it is *very hard* in C# to track ownership of raw pointers... I'd strongly recommend avoiding struct for your list unless you are the only user of that code and you manually review every copy operation on your lists.

Comment: @Dotlogix if your worry is really about the list itself, that's why list pools exist. It would be far more efficient to pool the lists than rewrite the entire class from scratch and have it be at least as good as the original. As to suggestions for your actual situation, here's two: run the tests in 64-bit and use a modern .Net. In fact you should never have to use actual pointers, spans would give you the same benefits in .Net 7.

Comment: @Charlieface thx for the suggestion you are actually totally right I changed it to use AggressiveInlining and NoInlining exactly what List does and now it is 10% faster than the List version.
Would you be so kind and convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Blindy thx for your comments, but this issue is more about experiments and memory alignment as you can not control memory alignment using normal Lists or Spans I used all techniques possible with usual C# Spans, Unsafe, MemoryMarshal.
And I also use Spans to wrap the native pointer to have the same benefits.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov also thx to you pointing this out. It will only be used internally so I have full control over what happens with this and why

Comment: With such small differences you are likely measuring compiler optimizations more than anything else. If you want an accurate answer you probably need to inspect the generated assembly code.

Comment: @Dotlogix, spans have nothing to do with memory allocation, aligned or not. And .Net provides methods to allocate aligned native memory as a first party API: [NativeMemory.AlignedAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.nativememory.alignedalloc?view=net-6.0).

Comment: There is exactly one thing you could improve from the provided `List<>`, and that's the whole versioning stuff it's doing -- I find that to be completely useless, or worse, just gets in the way when I know what I'm doing. However, having tried to copy the `List<>` class and removing the versioning code from it, I still couldn't match the original's performance. I'm convinced the JITter is cheating and special casing this class to be more efficient than we can write in regular C#.

Comment: @Blindy You can have the same performance using the AggressiveInlining trick in the accepted answer. The list I created is around 10% faster with 60% faster writes.
NativeMemory.AlignedAlloc works with bytes that's why it is abstracted away in the UnsafeUtils static class because I work with generics in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the [`List<T>` source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/bc70fec98fe39e63e194e7ffa30e9d1f44b4f254/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs#L195C9-L195C59), you may get a significant speedup by judicious use of `AggressiveInlining` and `NoInlining`. I don't have specific info on where to use it and where not, but it seems it is being used to inline the common paths, while keeping the uncommon paths in separate functions.

```cs
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private void EnsureCapacity(int count) {
```

```cs
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public void Add(T value) {
```

```cs
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
private void Resize(int capacity) {
```

---

Having said all that, I echo what others have said, that you are

- Probably optimizing the wrong thing. There are almost certainly worse inefficiencies in your code than the getters/setters on a `List`.
- Probably risking memory leaks (forgetting to use `using`), buffer overruns and other issues, for little gain.
- At the very least, you could probably improve your existing code by using `Span<T>` to store the `_buffer`, for little performance overhead (with the right placement of bounds checks so the Jitter can elide them). `Copy` in particular has very good optimization when using spans, because it unrolls it and uses SIMD instructions where possible.
- You should probably rethink why you even want to rewrite this at all, and not instead use some kind of `ListPool`, which would be the classic way of improving memory handling in games.
- I don't know what your `UnsafeUtils` does, but there is already functionality for [assigning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.nativememory.alignedalloc?view=net-6.0) and [freeing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.nativememory.alignedfree?view=net-6.0#system-runtime-interopservices-nativememory-alignedfree(system-void*)) aligned memory. See also [Create Memory Aligned Array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73269625/create-memory-aligned-array-in-c-sharp/73270404#73270404).

Comment: Just to add a few small things to this:

Span<T> is a ref struct and can neither be used as a class field nor could it be used in an async environment.

A list pool still does garbage collection when resizing the list and keeps a lot of memory allocated even if it is not needed anymore.

UnsafeUtils internally wraps some annoying missing methods like pointer additions and makes sure generic pointer arithmetic is done correctly void* is handled differently to T* in dotnet.

I totally agree with your points this is propably dangerous and only valid for a very limited use-case

Comment: Could use `Memory<T>` then. You could always create your own ListPool if you want. The whole *point* is it keeps around memory so you don't need to keep reallocating, that's what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness here is what I ended up with. And as mentioned by others, use this at your own risk. It can cause memory leaks and other issues.

It was a nice small thing for education and research and imho locking yourself behind a wall and ignoring the fact that you CAN do low-level stuff in C# is the wrong approach. A lot of optimizations in C# are based on more low-level operations.

You definetly have to be careful but it isn't more dangerous than classic C/C++.
It can improve performance beyond what is possible with the classic CLR.
For my use-case where I have to handle millions of reads/writes 5% - 10% speed boost is a LOT and I couldn't achieve that with any other method available.
Many SIMD instructions also benefit from aligned memory.

Anyway thank you all for your help and all of your suggestions.

##### Benchmark results:

| Method | Size | Mean | Error | StdDev | Ratio | CacheMisses/Op |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Native_Add | 100 | 928.46 ns | 9.469 ns | 8.857 ns | 1.05 | 1 |
| List_Add | 100 | 881.83 ns | 2.588 ns | 2.161 ns | 1.00 | 0 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Native_Add | 1000 | 8,853.17 ns | 25.682 ns | 24.023 ns | 0.98 | 2 |
| List_Add | 1000 | 9,047.41 ns | 74.998 ns | 70.153 ns | 1.00 | 7 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Native_Add | 10000 | 86,743.27 ns | 365.873 ns | 324.337 ns | 0.91 | 48 |
| List_Add | 10000 | 94,958.34 ns | 632.483 ns | 591.625 ns | 1.00 | 85 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Native_Get | 100 | 41.18 ns | 0.233 ns | 0.218 ns | 0.95 | 0 |
| List_Get | 100 | 43.12 ns | 0.416 ns | 0.389 ns | 1.00 | 0 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Native_Get | 1000 | 364.93 ns | 2.681 ns | 2.508 ns | 0.98 | 0 |
| List_Get | 1000 | 371.07 ns | 1.307 ns | 1.223 ns | 1.00 | 0 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Native_Get | 10000 | 3,639.95 ns | 12.656 ns | 11.838 ns | 0.99 | 38 |
| List_Get | 10000 | 3,682.92 ns | 32.122 ns | 30.047 ns | 1.00 | 3 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Native_Set | 100 | 55.42 ns | 0.530 ns | 0.496 ns | 0.34 | 0 |
| List_Set | 100 | 162.61 ns | 0.803 ns | 0.751 ns | 1.00 | 0 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Native_Set | 1000 | 492.16 ns | 6.839 ns | 6.397 ns | 0.29 | 1 |
| List_Set | 1000 | 1,672.13 ns | 19.912 ns | 18.626 ns | 1.00 | 2 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Native_Set | 10000 | 4,909.89 ns | 25.941 ns | 22.996 ns | 0.30 | 3 |
| List_Set | 10000 | 16,601.12 ns | 68.628 ns | 60.837 ns | 1.00 | 11 |

##### Code:

```cs
public unsafe struct NativeList<T> : IDisposable where T : unmanaged {
    private static readonly int MinCapacity = UnsafeUtils.CacheLineSize / sizeof(T);
    private T* _buffer;
    private int _capacity;
    private int _count;

    public int Capacity => _capacity;
    public int Count => _count;
    public T this[int index] {
        get {
            if((uint)index >= (uint)_count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
            return _buffer[index];
        }
        set {
            if((uint)index >= (uint)_count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
            _buffer[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public NativeList() {
    }

    public NativeList(int capacity) {
        if(capacity != 0) Resize(capacity);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public void Add(T value) {
        var buffer = _buffer;
        var count = _count;
        var capacity = _capacity;
        if ((uint)count < (uint)capacity) {
            _count = count + 1;
            buffer[count] = value;
        } else {
            AddWithResize(value);
        }
    }

    public void AddRange(T* values, int count) {
        if(count == 0) return;
        EnsureCapacity(count);
        UnsafeUtils.Copy<T>(values, 0, _buffer, _count, count);
        _count += count;
    }

    public bool Remove(T value) {
        var index = IndexOf(value);
        if(index < 0) return false;
        RemoveAt(index);
        return true;
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index) {
        if(index >= _count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));

        _count--;
        if(_count != index) {
            UnsafeUtils.Copy<T>(_buffer, index + 1, _buffer, index, _count - index);
        }
    }
    public void RemoveRangeAt(int index, int count) {
        if(index < 0 || index >= _count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
        if(count < 0 || index + count > _count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));
        if(count == 0) return;

        _count -= count;
        if(_count != index) {
            UnsafeUtils.Copy<T>(_buffer, index + count, _buffer, index, _count - index);
        }
        _count -= count;
    }

    public bool Contains(T value) {
        return IndexOf(value, EqualityComparer<T>.Default) >= 0;
    }

    public bool Contains(T value, IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer) {
        return IndexOf(value, equalityComparer) >= 0;
    }
    
    public int IndexOf(T value) {
        return IndexOf(value, EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
    }

    public int IndexOf(T value, IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer) {
        for(var i = 0; i < _count; i++) {
            if(equalityComparer.Equals(_buffer[i], value)) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    
    public void Clear() {
        _count = 0;
    }
    
    public Span<T> AsSpan() {
        return UnsafeUtils.CreateSpan<T>(_buffer, _count);
    }

    public Enumerator GetEnumerator() {
        return new Enumerator(_buffer, _count);
    }

    private void EnsureCapacity(int count) {
        var minCapacity = _count + count;
        if(minCapacity > _capacity) Resize(minCapacity);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private void AddWithResize(T value) {
        var count = _count;
        
        Resize(count + 1);
        _count = count + 1;
        _buffer[_count] = value;
    }

    private void Resize(int capacity) {
        capacity = Math.Max(MinCapacity, (int)BitOperations.RoundUpToPowerOf2((uint)capacity));
        _buffer = (T*)UnsafeUtils.AlignedRealloc<T>(_buffer, capacity);
        _capacity = capacity;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        if(_buffer is null) return;
        UnsafeUtils.AlignedFree(_buffer);
        _capacity = 0;
        _buffer = null;
    }

    public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<T> {
        private readonly void* _buffer;
        private readonly int _count;
        private int _index;
        
        public T Current { get; private set; }
        object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

        public Enumerator(void* buffer, int count) {
            _buffer = buffer;
            _count = count;
            _index = -1;
        }

        public bool MoveNext() {
            if(++_index >= _count) return false;
            Current = ((T*)_buffer)[_index];
            return true;
        }

        public void Reset() {
            _index = -1;
        }
        public void Dispose() {}
    }
}
```

```cs
public static unsafe class UnsafeUtils {
    public const int CacheLineSize = 64;
    public static readonly int PointerSize = Unsafe.SizeOf<nuint>();

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static Span<T> CreateSpan<T>(void* pointer, int count) where T : unmanaged {
        return new Span<T>(pointer, count);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static Span<T> CreateSpan<T>(void* pointer, int index, int count) where T : unmanaged {
        return new Span<T>(Unsafe.Add<T>(pointer, index), count);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static int SizeOf<T>() where T : unmanaged {
        return sizeof(T);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static int AlignmentOf<T>() where T : unmanaged {
        return sizeof(AlignmentHelper<T>) - sizeof(T);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static int ByteCount<T>(int count) where T : unmanaged {
        return count * sizeof(T);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void* AlignedAlloc<T>(int count) where T : unmanaged {
        if(count <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));
        return NativeMemory.AlignedAlloc((nuint)ByteCount<T>(count), (nuint)AlignmentOf<T>());
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void* AlignedRealloc<T>(void* source, int count) where T : unmanaged {
        if(count <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));
        return NativeMemory.AlignedRealloc(source, (nuint)ByteCount<T>(count), (nuint)AlignmentOf<T>());
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void AlignedFree(void* pointer) {
        NativeMemory.AlignedFree(pointer);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void* Alloc<T>(int count) where T : unmanaged {
        if(count <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));
        return NativeMemory.Alloc((nuint)ByteCount<T>(count));
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void* Realloc<T>(void* source, int count) where T : unmanaged {
        if(count <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));
        return NativeMemory.Realloc(source, (nuint)ByteCount<T>(count));
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Free(void* pointer) {
        NativeMemory.Free(pointer);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static int IndexOf<T>(void* source, int count, T value) where T : unmanaged, IEquatable<T> {
        return CreateSpan<T>(source, count).IndexOf(value);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static int IndexOf<T>(void* source, int index, int count, T value) where T : unmanaged, IEquatable<T> {
        return CreateSpan<T>(source, index, count).IndexOf(value);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static int LastIndexOf<T>(void* source, int count, T value) where T : unmanaged, IEquatable<T> {
        return CreateSpan<T>(source, count).LastIndexOf(value);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static int LastIndexOf<T>(void* source, int index, int count, T value) where T : unmanaged, IEquatable<T> {
        return CreateSpan<T>(source, index, count).LastIndexOf(value);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static bool Contains<T>(void* source, int count, T value) where T : unmanaged, IEquatable<T> {
        return CreateSpan<T>(source, count).Contains(value);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static bool Contains<T>(void* source, int index, int count, T value) where T : unmanaged, IEquatable<T> {
        return CreateSpan<T>(source, index, count).Contains(value);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Clear(void* destination, int byteCount) {
        NativeMemory.Clear(destination, (nuint)byteCount);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Clear(void* destination, int index, int byteCount) {
        NativeMemory.Clear((byte*)destination + index, (nuint)byteCount);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Clear<T>(void* destination, int count) where T : unmanaged {
        CreateSpan<T>(destination, count).Clear();
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Clear<T>(void* destination, int index, int count) where T : unmanaged {
        CreateSpan<T>(destination, index, count).Clear();
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Copy(void* source, void* destination, int byteCount) {
        NativeMemory.Copy(source, destination, (nuint)byteCount);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Copy(void* source, int sourceByteIndex, void* destination, int destinationByteIndex, int byteCount) {
        NativeMemory.Copy((byte*)source + sourceByteIndex, (byte*)destination + destinationByteIndex, (nuint)byteCount);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Copy<T>(void* source, void* destination, int count) where T : unmanaged {
        var sourceSpan = CreateSpan<T>(source, count);
        var destinationSpan = CreateSpan<T>(destination, count);
        sourceSpan.CopyTo(destinationSpan);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Copy<T>(void* source, int sourceIndex, void* destination, int destinationIndex, int count) where T : unmanaged {
        var sourceSpan = CreateSpan<T>(source, sourceIndex, count);
        var destinationSpan = CreateSpan<T>(destination, destinationIndex, count);
        sourceSpan.CopyTo(destinationSpan);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Fill(void* destination, int byteCount, byte value) {
        NativeMemory.Fill(destination, (nuint)byteCount, value);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Fill(void* destination, int index, int byteCount, byte value) {
        NativeMemory.Fill((byte*)destination + index, (nuint)byteCount, value);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Fill<T>(void* destination, int count, T value) where T : unmanaged {
        var destinationSpan = CreateSpan<T>(destination, count);
        destinationSpan.Fill(value);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Fill<T>(void* destination, int index, int count, T value) where T : unmanaged {
        var destinationSpan = CreateSpan<T>(destination, index, count);
        destinationSpan.Fill(value);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static ref T AsRef<T>(void* source) {
        return ref Unsafe.AsRef<T>(source);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static ref T AsRef<T>(void* source, int index) {
        return ref Unsafe.AsRef<T>(Unsafe.Add<T>(source, index));
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Write<T>(void* destination, T value) {
        Unsafe.Write(destination, value);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Write<T>(void* destination, int index, T value) {
        Unsafe.Write(Unsafe.Add<T>(destination, index), value);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void WriteUnaligned<T>(void* destination, T value) {
        Unsafe.WriteUnaligned(destination, value);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void WriteUnaligned<T>(void* destination, int index, T value) {
        Unsafe.WriteUnaligned(Unsafe.Add<T>(destination, index), value);
    }

    public static T Read<T>(void* source) {
        return Unsafe.Read<T>(source);
    }

    public static T Read<T>(void* source, int index) {
        return Unsafe.Read<T>(Unsafe.Add<T>(source, index));
    }

    public static T ReadUnaligned<T>(void* source) {
        return Unsafe.ReadUnaligned<T>(source);
    }

    public static T ReadUnaligned<T>(void* source, int index) {
        return Unsafe.ReadUnaligned<T>(Unsafe.Add<T>(source, index));
    }

    public static void* Add<T>(void* source, int count) where T : unmanaged {
        return Unsafe.Add<T>(source, count);
    }

    public static void* Subtract<T>(void* source, int count) where T : unmanaged {
        return Unsafe.Subtract<T>(source, count);
    }

    [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "NotAccessedPositionalProperty.Local")]
    private readonly record struct AlignmentHelper<T>(byte Dummy, T Value) where T : unmanaged;
}
```